# BuildConfigField R.style.AKTheme is not accessible in androidTest BuildConfig.java class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

My project has different build types i.e. debug, beta and production and also have different product flavors i.e. QA and Integration. I have defined 
a

`buildConfigField 'int', 'APP_THEME', 'R.style.AKTheme'`

in the productFlavors to have a separate theme for each flavor. The generated `BuildConfig.java` for app source set have the `APP_THEME field` and it is working as expected.

Recently I have started writing instrumentation tests for my app. When I try to run these tests Android studio gives me the error that **can not resolve AKTheme** i.e.

`final int APP_THEME = R.style.AKTheme` in the generated `BuildConfig.java` for the test source set.

It seems that `R.style.AKTheme` is not accessible to the generated `BuildConfig.java` file (test source set). I searched over internet but didn't find any help.

Comment: That seems like a wrong way to change theme based on flavors. Better do it using different sourceSets
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants
That being said run `sourceSets` task and examine the output to see which folders are being picked in your test. From gradle window MyApplication > Tasks > android and double-click sourceSets.

Answer (score 1):

`R.style.AKTheme` is a reference, not a value, while in BuildConfig you can only use values.
There are couple of ways to achieve what you want:

1. Use the String name of the style in BuildConfig:
   `buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_THEME', '"AKTheme"'`
   and then in code to get the style res id:
   `int style = context.getResources().getIdentifier(BuildConfig.APP_THEME, "style", context.getPackageName());`
   Now you can use `style`.
2. You can use different source-sets.
   If you are using different buildtypes, you can create a directory for that build type, and put any different resources specially for that build type in that directory. The directory should be created in the same directory as `main` sources directory, and named exactly the same as the buildType. Details: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Answer (score 0):

I had quite the same issue. I had this in my build.gradle to get the right ssl certificate depending on the env. :

```
buildConfigField 'int', 'SSL_CERTIFICAT_RAWRES_', 'R.raw.devcert'
```

This was working to build and run the project, but I faced an issue when I wanted to run the task : "compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac" (used for sonarqube in my case). The compiler didn't found the resource file R when he automatically generates the buildConfig file.

The solution was to put a String to identify my certificate file "devcert" in the build.gradle instead of using directly the resInt "R.raw" :

```
buildConfigField 'String', 'SSL_CERTIFICAT_RAWRES_STRING', '"devcert"'
```

and then in my code, I get the raw file certificate like this :

```
final int raw = context.getResources().getIdentifier(BuildConfig.SSL_CERTIFICAT_RAWRES_STRING, "raw", context.getPackageName());
```

That way, the generated buildConfig found correctly the String identifier to retrieve the wanted raw file using the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: https://developer.android.com/studio/test#create_instrumented_test_for_a_build_variant

For my case my test project and my main project is referencing a different package name, e.g. at the top of BuildConfig.java one referencing to package 'com.xxx.xxx' while one is referencing to 'com.xxx.xxx.test'

adding the line

> testApplicationId = "com.xxx.xxx"

in defaultConfig in app level build.gradle file solves the issue for me